# Automatically create tags and merge with categories

Tags: categories, tags, automation

In the following code I can set tags automatically and add to a pre-existing category:

```
<?php function update_post_terms( $post_id ) {
    if ( $parent = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        $post_id = $parent;
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    if ( $post->post_type != 'post' )
        return;

    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, 'News from, Videos from, Books from', 'post_tag', true );

    wp_set_post_categories( $post_id );
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'update_post_terms' ); ?>
```

What I'm trying to do is take 3 tags that will be created automatically, and merge with the category added to the post.

For example: *News from, Videos from, Books from* (3 predefined tags).

If I create the Technology category, when publishing the tags would be created: *News from Technology, Videos from Technology, Books from Technology.*

Comment: How do you connect the post to the Technology category? If every post in category X also has 3 tags of `Something from X` what's the point of the tags?

Comment: This is just an example. It could be used, for example, on a quote site. If I create a category with the writer's name, automatic tags would be created such as: _Quotes from Thomas Jefferson, Biography from Thomas Jefferson, Works from Thomas Jefferson._

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-edit-categories-tags/

Best regards

Comment: The plugin has many functions, but not exactly what I'm looking for. And most functions are premium and cost $59.99.